# Spinnaker - Automated Triggers not working

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

I have configured the Automated Triggers as mentioned below

1. Added the webhook in Github

[image]

2. Updated the spinnaker configuration

   kubectl exec --namespace spinnaker -it spinnaker-spinnaker-halyard-0 bash

   hal config features edit --artifacts true
   hal config artifact github enable

   hal config artifact github account add kavija --token xxxxx

   hal deploy apply
3. Configured the pipeline
   [image]
4. It looks like webhook is delivered
   [image]

[image]

5. Spinnaker pipeline is not auto-triggered
   [image]

What am I missing?

5.

Comment: Maybe not all of the Expected Artifacts configured for the pipeline match? [Spinnaker docs](https://spinnaker.io/guides/user/pipeline/triggers/github/#configure-the-github-artifact) mentions: "If no artifact for this description is present, the pipeline won’t start."

Comment: Also, what version of Spinnaker are you using? This may very well be a [Spinnaker bug](https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker/issues/5645).